# IBM Worklight - Encrypted Offline Cache and alternatives

Tags: html, cross-platform, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

In IBM Worklight Documentation I can read "HTML5 cache, as used in EOC, is not guaranteed to be persistent on future iOS versions"
So, I have some questions:

- Does it still work on iOS7 ?
- Why will it be avoided ?
- What is the alternative, if we are targeting iOS, Android, Blackberry and Windows Phone ?

I have read also that JSONStore works only for Android and iOS. Is there a way to get it working on BlackBerry and Windows Phone?
Is the support of these platforms planned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have read also that JSONStore works only for Android and iOS. Is
>   there a way to get it working on BlackBerry and Windows Phone? Is the
>   support of these platforms planned?

It is not possible to manually extend JSONStore support to more platforms.
Can't comment on future plans...

Encrypted Offline Cache:

- works in iOS 7
- "Why will it be avoided?" - not sure what that means.

Comment: What about the question "What is the alternative, if we are targeting iOS, Android, Blackberry and Windows Phone ?"

Comment: Use different methods.